# weblogic admin hangs and not returning any result

Tags: shell, weblogic

I'm using shell script to monitor WebLogic server status. Following is the script line to monitor.

```
java weblogic.Admin -url t3://myhostip:myport -username adminuser -password mypassword GETSTATE
```

In case of failure this line not returning any thing and hangs on this point. So is there any way to set time out to passe through this line in this script?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this *the gardener way* - I mean it is a little do-it-yourself style :) -  with [nohup](/questions/tagged/nohup):

First put your command in a shell if possible, then call it with `nohup`:

```
nohup your_command.sh 2>&1 > mylog.out &
```

Then sleep the time you want to wait

```
sleep ${MY_TIME_OUT}
```

After collect the process id ([pid](/questions/tagged/pid)) after a while

```
x=`ps -eaf|grep your_command.sh|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}' `
```

If `x` contains nothing, then `your_command.sh` returned successfully. Otherwise you can hard-kill it so:

```
if [[ "${x}" != "" ]] ; then echo "killing ${x}"; kill -9 ${x} ; fi
```

Hope it helps